# What does で do in this?

Tags: grammar, particle-で

> 弱い冒険者からは階層主という名**で**恐れられているように、.....

Is で marking the agent of the passive sentence? I thought you had to use に.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this 階層主 is feared by 弱い冒険者, which is marked by から in this sentence. Some verbs can take から instead of に when in passive voice.

> - 私は彼**に**見下された ＝ 私は彼**から**見下された ＝ I was looked down by him.
> - 上司**に**仕事を任された　＝　上司**から**仕事を任された　＝ I was assigned a task by my boss.

(BTW irregular prepositions are also found in English passive sentences, for example "I was surprised *at* ...", "He was known *to* ...")

---

And this で is not directly related to passive voice, but is a particle which corresponds to "under" in "**under** the name of 階層主."

> 弱い冒険者からは階層主という名で恐れられているように、...
>   ＝ 弱い冒険者**に**は階層主という名で恐れられているように、...
>   ＝ As he is feared by low-rank adventurers under the name of 階層主, ...